# Rails 3 caching and image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, imagemagick

In my rails application I have a feature that allows users to rotate their uploaded images. On the backend I'm simply using ImageMagick's `convert` to rotate the image.

The problem I have is with the `image_tag` helper. As I understand it, `image_tag` adds a timestamp to the end of the file path to aid with browser caching. However, the timestamp isn't changing after applying `convert` and refreshing the page, so the user doesn't see any change in their image.

I'm thinking this has something to do with the entire view being cached by rails? I'm not sure if that is the case and some time spent on Google didn't really make it clear if that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make the URL to the image unique for each page load, which would bust the browser cache:

```
<%= image_tag "name_of_image.png?#{Time.now.to_f}" %>
```

Comment: Yeah that is an option, but browser caching is ok in general. I would prefer the image to be cached until it is rotated.

Comment: Maybe use the last updated date for the image then instead of `Time.now`.  Or...save the rotated image with a different name than the original.

Comment: Yeah those are both fine solutions that I may end up using, but it really would be nice to figure out exactly why `image_tag` is not behaving the way I expect it to.

Comment: What are you expecting the image_tag to do?  It adds the digest to the end of image urls for assets that are in the pipeline.  And, the digest only changes when you re-compile the assets.  The browser still caches these...

Comment: These assets are uploaded by users, so they are in `public`. This is not precompiled, am I right? Maybe that's the problem, that `image_tag` doesn't read the modified date of these images to create the digest string anyway?

Comment: Correct.  The file with the digest in it's name is generated when you run `rake assets:precompile`.  The digest only changes if the asset itself changes AND if you re-run the pre-compile (there are some weird exceptions to this with js and css manifest files).

Comment: Thanks for talking that through with me. I see now that something closer to your original suggestion is what I need to do.